# Java applet display problem when i add it to dom tree via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, applet

I have a modal popup as (lightbox etc.). If i want to add java applet into the modal popup via javascript i encounter a problem that is Java Applet don't display propperly sometimes dont' everytime. I tried to solve it setTimeout methot but it didn't solve :( Do you have a suggestion this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mind showing some code?

If what you're trying to do is use DOM scripting to add an `<applet>` then check out this demo: 
http://kaioa.com/b/0708/applet_dom_inject.html

It's from these tutorials on Delayed Applet Loading: 
http://kaioa.com/node/21